# Mysql column count doesn't match value count fix for unattended

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite

I have to import loads of files into a database, the problem is, with time it got more columns.

The files are all insert-lines from SQLite, but i need them in MySQL, SQLIte doesn't provide column-names in their sql files, so the MySQL-script crashes when there are more or less columns as in the insert statement.

Is there a solution for this? Maybe over a join?

The new added columns are in the end, so the first are ALWAYS the same.
Is there any possibility to insert the sql-file in a temporary table, then make a join on an empty table (or 1 ghost record) to get the right amount of columns, and then do a insert on each line from that table to the table i want to have the data in?

Files looks like:

```
INSERT into theTable Values (1,1,Text,2913, txt,);
```

And if columns were added the file is like

```
INSERT into theTable Values (1,1,Text,2913, txt,added-Text);
```

Comment: there is no added columns. there is just missed `null` in the first query

Comment: no, the columns changed, i see it in the SQLite database. in 2014 there were only 26, in 2015 29.